# How to calculate occurrence of each item from an array within a cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have list of items in an array and in another column, I have cells where merged items exists. I am trying to calculate how many of these items from the array exist in each cell. How can I do that on Google Sheets with functions?

```
A         B   C
a,b,c,d   3   b
c,b,x,y   2   c
x,y,z     0   d
```

Array exists in C column and number of occurrences in each cell under A column will be in B column. Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why b=3 and d=0? I see b=2 and d=1.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no relation between numbers and c column. C column is the array {b,c,d}. So the formula needs to search and tell us how many of these array items exist in column A. For example, "a,b,c,d" includes 3 of the array items while "c,b,x,y" includes only two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for line 2

```
=sum(arrayformula(countif(split(A2,","),$C$2:$C)))
```

and then duplicate for other lines